# Launching an application with admin priviledge in non admin session

Tags: windows-10, administrator, active-directory, elevation

In our company, we maintain and deploy a native binary application to our clients' Windows 10 systems.
They used to be able to execute it with admin privilege while being in a non admin session, but since the beginning of June 2023 they have to input user and password of an admin session to execute our app.
It seems to come from one of the vulnerability fix that Microsoft released during the month
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-june-2023-patch-tuesday-fixes-78-flaws-38-rce-bugs/.

I wanted to know if other people had a similar problem and also if there is a way to launch the app with admin privileges on a non admin session without having to input user/password of an admin session.
Also, if there is a way to do it using Active Directory (with GPOs maybe ?) that could do it, since our users use sessions managed by it.

Comment: Your analysis of the problem is wrong. A standard user on Windows 10 (and even before) was never able to run an elevated command with admin privilege.

Comment: It sounds weird to me too, but in fact that's how it was. The sessions privileges did not change, we were and we are launching the app in admin mode and no other parameters have changed. The only change that seem to have happened is the Windows' update.

Comment: An app only needs Admin rights if it either needs to read/write to a location the user does not have access to, such as program files, or an area in the registry, such as HKLM. For both, if you have admin access, you can set permissions once, and then the standard user does not need admin rights anymore. Its likely admin rights were never necessary, but security permissions have changed. Also, if an app adjusts system settings or manages services, admin access is always necessary.

Comment: I agree, the Windows Update explanation is very unlikely. The likely explanation is that it's due to some local administrative change of permissions.